# How to add Let's Encrypt key/cert to Payara Micro using asadmin boot script

Tags: docker, payara, payara-micro

I successfully generated a Let's Encrypt certificate for my set using a the certbot standalone server, but now I want to move those into a payara micro container for production. Payara Micro allows me to put asadmin commands in pre/post scripts that it picks up and runs.

First, here is the docker command to create the container:

```
docker run -p 8765:8090 \
           --mount type=bind,src=$(pwd)/deployments,dst=/opt/payara/deployments \
           --mount type=bind,src=$(pwd)/lib,dst=/opt/payara/lib \
           --mount type=bind,src=$(pwd)/cert,dst=/opt/payara/cert \
           --mount type=bind,src=$(pwd)/scripts,dst=/opt/payara/scripts \
           --env-file payara.env \
           --restart=always \
           payara/micro:5.191 \
           --prebootcommandfile /opt/payara/scripts/preboot.asadmin \
           --addlibs /opt/payara/lib \
           --deploy /opt/payara/deployments/MyApp.war \
           --sslport 8090 \
           --sslcert le_myapp \
           --contextroot ROOT
```

The `preboot.asadmin` script has one line:

```
add-pkcs8 --domain_name production --destalias "le_myapp" --priv-key-path /opt/payara/cert/privkey.pem --cert-chain-path /etc/letsencrypt/opt/payara/cert/fullchain.pem
```

Of course, registering the cert fails, and the log doesn't provide any useful information as to why it failed:

```
[2019-05-29T16:41:48.329+0000] [] [WARNING] [] [fish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommand] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1559148108329] [levelValue: 900] Boot Command add-pkcs8 failed Exception while executing command. 

[2019-05-29T16:41:48.999+0000] [] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommand] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1559148108999] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Boot Command set returned with result SUCCESS : PlainTextActionReporterSUCCESSDescription: set AdminCommandnull
    configs.config.server-config.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.https-listener.port=8090
]]

[2019-05-29T16:41:49.042+0000] [] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommand] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1559148109042] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Boot Command set returned with result SUCCESS : PlainTextActionReporterSUCCESSDescription: set AdminCommandnull
    configs.config.server-config.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.https-listener.enabled=true
]]

[2019-05-29T16:41:49.114+0000] [] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommand] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1559148109114] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Boot Command set returned with result SUCCESS : PlainTextActionReporterSUCCESSDescription: set AdminCommandnull
    configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.https-listener.ssl.cert-nickname=le_myapp
]]
```

UPDATE 1:

I filed an issue with [payara/Payara/issues/4010](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/4010) because I think it's a problem with command on the Micro edition. If there is an update to that issue I will post an update here.

UPDATE 2:

As suggested on the github issue, I removed `--domain_name production` from the command.  I even tried the non-micro `payara/server-web:5.192`.  Neither worked.  Applying the same asadmin command on a native installation works just fine.